# Why is asp-route-id helper not mapping in accordance with my RouteAttribute template?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

I have a ASP.NET CORE endpoint with a RouteAttribute:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("MyController/MyAction/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(int id, string rc)
{
    ...
```

Notice that I'm expecting `id` to be passed as a part of the URL, and `rc` to be passed as a query string.

And I have an MVC razor page that is supposed to be using the anchor helpers to create a link to this controller:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <a asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="MyAction"
        asp-route-id="@item.Id" asp-route-rc=@item.Rc>Execute</a>
}
```

I'd expect this to create an anchor with the link:

```
http://localhost:5000/MyController/MyAction/1?rc=234
```

But instead it creates an anchor with the link:

```
http://localhost:5000/MyController/MyAction?id=1&rc=234
```

In other words, it's sending `id` as a query string, and not as part of the URL, despite the template declaration in the `RouteAttribute`.

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Show your ednpoints in startup class. This is why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to configure the endpoints like this in your startup if you want it works the way you want

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            });
```

When you use id in default route, html helper  put the  id value in your default route at id place. You can use another name instead of id. And then you can use this name in html helpers.  Not default names are adding to the url as a query string parameters.

if in your startup

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();

});
```

then you are supposed to use mostly attribute routing

Comment: It was my understanding that what I specified on a given controller action using RouteAttribute over-rode what was specified in MapControllerRoute().

That is, what you're doing in MapControllerRoute() specifies a default that applies only to endpoints that don't have a route template specified.

Comment: @JeffDege It is all extremely complicated to explain. You have to understand this. Just try this routing and let me know if it works or not. Since I never used routing the way you use I  don' t have any idea what will happen.

Comment: I tried adding "/{id?}" to the default route, and now things work.

I really don't understand why.

Comment: @JeffDege I added some explanations to my answer.